# Flip Book in javascript+flash when flip book folder is outside of project folder

Tags: javascript, flash

I have created a flip book using JavaScript and flash. That flip book is working fine when we keep flip book folder i.e. book pages and SWF and other supporting file on project root directory. But it is not working when I want to store this file outside of the project folder or on some other drive.

Does anyone know how I can do this?